# Change DocumentRoot in Apache depending on URL path

Tags: apache

I'm redoing my API. Fortunately, its versioned. Yay! But what's the best way to handle the new code.

Basically; I have `api.example.com/v1/method` etc. My site runs on apache, and `api.example.com` points to `/var/www/html/api.example.com`

For the new API, I will be using a completely different framework and codebase etc, so I don't want to mix up the files.

Ideally, what I want is `api.example.com/v1/` to point to `/var/www/html/api-v1.example.com` and `api.example.com/v2/` to point to `/var/www/html/api-v2.example.com`.

[Edited, I originally said subdirectories which I think is confusing, but really I think I want them as completely separate sites]

Is this possible using Apache?

Additional question: if instead of using `/v1/` `/v2/` etc, I versioned my API by using an Accept header like:

```
Accept: application/vnd.api-example-com-v2+json
```

how would I map that to a different directory?

Comment: Sure it's possible, what exactly is the problem? Create `v2` in parallel to `v1` and that should do it. I probably do not understand the question. :-)

Comment: I wouldn’t use HTTP headers for the API version – makes it more difficult to implement for you as well as for the people using your API. Specifying the version within the URL is perfectly fine IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine if you have your document root setup as

```
/var/www/html/api.example.com
```

Then have the directories `/v1/` and `/v2/` inside the document root. As for the **Accept** header. You can match against that using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/vnd.api-example-com-(.*)\+json
RewriteCond %1::$1 !^(.*)::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

---

If that's what you want, then you need to create some aliases in your vhost/server config:

```
AliasMatch ^/v([0-9]+)/(.*)$  /var/www/html/api-v$1.example.com/$2
```

Comment: See my edit; I think I really want them as separate sites, with separate base directories. And api.example.com/method would respond with the latest version of the API.

Comment: Great - AliasMatch looks like it works perfect for my current use case. Presumably I would need something else for the HTTP_ACCEPT version?

Comment: @Apemantus I don't think so, when it gets rewritten to `/v1/` or `/v2/` or whatever, the alias should take care of it from there. Else you can also do a redirect by adding a `R` flag in the square brackets: `[L,R]`